# Error when building TEB local planner: "Target 'tf' of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another target"

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When building the latest version of [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) in ROS Kinect from source, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at teb-local-planner/CMakeLists.txt:197 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "tf" of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another target.  One
  may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the
  ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.


CMake Error at teb-local-planner/CMakeLists.txt:208 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "tf" of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another target.  One
  may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the
  ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.
```

Cheking the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner/blob/kinetic-devel/CMakeLists.txt) file, lines 197 and 208 correspond to `target_link_libraries()` directives; when checking the value of `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` I do see a reference to the `tf` executable.

Why is `catkin` adding the `tf` executable to the libraries variable?

**Edit:** I'm running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) and Intel notebook, with cmake 3.5.1 and gcc 5.4.0.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281412/error-when-building-teb-local-planner:-%22target-%27tf%27-of-type-executable-may-not-be-linked-into-another-target%22/) by [xperroni](https://answers.ros.org/users/26539/xperroni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xperroni](https://answers.ros.org/users/26539/xperroni/) on 2018-01-31**:
I still don't understand why `catkin` is doing that, but I noticed that compiling with `catkin_make_isolated` instead of `catkin_make` seems to avoid the issue, whatever its cause.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-31**:
I think it'd help if you could give a little bit more info (as these sort of things tend to be highly platform/os/version of CMake dependent). So: could you add your platform, OS and version of relevant parts of your build chain (ie: gcc)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-31**:
Just an observation: Kinetic was specced with CMake `3.0.2` (see [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021)). You're running `3.5.1`. That is quite a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_make builds with all packages in a combined cmake workspace, which means that target names are used for dependencies between packages. When using catkin_make_isolated or catkin build, packages are built in separate workspaces, and these dependencies use library names.

Since the `tf` package probably exports and library target named `tf`, and since teb_local_planner depends on `tf`, that target name gets added `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`.

I suspect that you have another executable target named `tf` somewhere in your workspace, and cmake is getting the executable and library targets confused. Try to find another package with something like `add_executable(tf ....)`, comment out that executable and try rebuilding.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2018-12-15**:
Worked like a charm!!!